# How To remove everything which is visible on current View and then display a different view?

Tags: iphone, uiview

In my i have a screen where i added different components like buttons, labels etc through different steps. Now after a click i want to remove everything and display another view.
Here's some code:

```
-(void)estimateButtons:(NSString *)text andFrameX:(int)x andFrameY:(int)y andFrameW:(int)w andFrameH:(int)h 
{
    estimate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    estimate.frame =CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
    //[estimate setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage * buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_green_estimate.png"];
    UIImage * strechableButtonImage = [buttonImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [estimate setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [estimate addTarget:self action:@selector(estimateSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:estimate];
}

-(void)estimateSelected:(UIButton *)b
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];    
    graph = [[SFNDoorBarGraphVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"SFNDoorBarGraphVC" bundle:nil];
    [graph.view setCenter:CGPointMake(350, 660)];
    [self.view addSubview:graph.view];
}
```

With this code its removing everything but its not displaying the content of my new view which is graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

so when you:

```
[self.view addSubview:graph.view];
```

the graph view is added to a view that is not in the view hierarchy.

try this:

```
NSArray *sViews = [self.view subviews];
[sViews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

EDIT: Adding as per request in the comments.

```
NSArray *sViews = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *sv in sViews)
{
     if (![sv isEqual:viewToSave])
     {
           [sv removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
```

Comment: That worked !!!! Thanks a lot. Is there a way to save a view from deletion but not rest.

Answer (score 1):

Get the subviews of your current view controller using

```
[self.view subviews];
```

This returns an array of subviews. You can loop through them and for each view you can call:

```
[currView removeFromSuperview];
```

where currView will be a reference to the subview as you are looping through.

Comment: Could your elaborate a little more.

Comment: Also the problem is not with the removal but with displaying the new view.

Comment: I got the array but cannot loop through it to remove the desired ones. The answer above let me remove everything and display my content. But now i want to remove just the specific ones and keep the rest. How should i do it??